# Civilization - Through the Ages with old game

Tags: through-the-ages

I own the 'old' version of Through the Ages: A Story of Civilization from 2006. 
There is also a new version (Through the Ages: A New Story of Civilization) from 2015.

Some rules have been added and cards have been changed (among others).

I'm wondering if I can play the new rules, or some adapted rules with the old game.

It's too much work creating/altering the cards, but if there are not many changes it might be worthwhile. Or can some or all rules of the new game be played with the old game as well?